# Local Variable not showing all the values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to programming so I do not know how this question to ask.

what I am doing is firstly finding @userid value on different query, then after when I do

```
select a,b
from tableA
where userid = @userid  
and active=1
and payments=1
```

then it executes to show me number of rows(lets say:10 rows)

but when I do like below, I only get 1 row (I want to get all 10 rows):

```
  declare @A varchar(10)
  declare @B bigint

  select @A=a,@B=b
  from tableA
  where userid=@userid
  and active=1
  and payments=1

  Select @A,@B
```

so, I am asking for help how do I do this . I have to do like step 2 because i have to run other query taking,@A and @B

Answer (score 2):

Yes because those are scalar variable which can hold only 1 item and in your case it will hold the values for last row. You might want to consider using a table variable rather. Like

```
DECLARE @tab1 table(
 A varchar(10),
 B bigint );
```

Then fill it like

```
insert into @tab1(A,B)
  select a, b
  from tableA
  where userid=@userid
  and active=1
  and payments=1
```

Now select from it

```
select * from @tab1;
```

Comment: I totally agree Rahul,
I am inserting this in #temp table
so when i do 
insert into #temp
(
colm1,colm2
)
select a,b
from tableA
where userid=@userid
and active=1
and payment=1

then I have all rows, ok but I want to use the a,b value to other query below to that.
OR lets say:

I have to count rows and if rows is greater than 1 and less than 18 I have to update the temp table 
in this case how is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do something with all a and b values of tableA.

You can use cursor for that if number of records are small else use the WHILE loop to read each record.

```
Declare @a varchar(10)
Declare @b varchar(10)

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR  
select a, b
from tableA
where userid=@userid
and active=1
and payments=1

    OPEN MyCursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a, @b   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       Select @a, @b
       FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @a, @b  
END   
CLOSE MyCursor   
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```